# MKMapView showing blank screen in iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, ios8, xcode6

I am having an issue with displaying a MKMapView in iOS 8.

It worked fine in iOS 7 and it is working fine now but only on simulator.

On device it shows only annotations but no map behind.

It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SenGt.jpg

The error that I am getting:

```
2014-09-24 22:07:15.349 xxx[1509:265380] Stylesheet does not include style matching tree, or includes an old version.  Perhaps it was compiled by an old version of the style compiler.
2014-09-24 22:07:15.351 xxx[1509:265380] Please create a radar about this! (Check it's not a dup of rdar://16346611 first though)
2014-09-24 22:07:15.351 xxx[1509:265380] Active tile set: GEOActiveTileSet
```

My code:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.779998, 59.447816);

    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.007, 0.007);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [annotation setCoordinate:coord];
    [annotation setTitle:@"yyy"];

    [self.cell.myMapView setRegion:region];
    [self.cell.myMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    [self.cell.myMapView setDelegate:self];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I experience exactly the same. Was working fine in ios7 and is still fine in simulator but crashing on ios8. Have you submitted a bug report to Apple?

Comment: I also face same.. Guys have you got some solution?

Comment: I'm getting that error message using MapKit on Yosemite.  I get the feeling it's not that significant.

Answer (score 2):

Link CoreGraphics framework to your target. Should fix that.