# Getting this error when using MKMapView! : "fatal error unexpectedley found nil while unwrapping optional value"

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

Im trying to show the user's location and a map of the location using MKMapView but I get an error when doing so. I get an error for this line of code: map.delegate = self. Here's the full code, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. I looked at other tutorials and they have it the same way I have it setup and it works for them. Thank you!

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit



class MapScene: SKScene, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
var locationMangaer = CLLocationManager()
var map : MKMapView!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    locationMangaer.delegate = self
    locationMangaer.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationMangaer.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationMangaer.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationMangaer.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    map.delegate = self
    map.showsUserLocation = true


}



//DELEGATE METHODS

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

    println("error")
}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {


    var userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
    locationMangaer.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    map.centerCoordinate = userLocation.coordinate


    println("call")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried your code. Make it work with the following changes:

Comment out

```
locationMangaer.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

Comment out

```
mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.coordinate
```

Add the following String entry to Info.plist:

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

with any text.

Comment: I did what you said and I don't see the map. I only get a black screen.

Comment: Does it matter that im in SpriteKit?

Comment: @coding22 try to instantiate `MKMapView` manually as `let map = MKMapView()`. I've used `IBOutlet` for testing. Think it doesn't matter. Try to add `println(error)` in error delegate function, curious what may be there.

Comment: I don't get an error when I do this and nothing prints out in the console and there is no  map. Also I tried using an IBOutlet and the map shows up but I need it to come when I press a button. How would I do that?

Comment: @coding22 make the map with `alpha = 0.0`, and then animate it on button press via `UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in map.alpha = 1.0 })`

Answer (score 3):

When you declare your map variable, you do not provide a default value, and it doesn't instantiate properly.

What you need to do is hook it up to a view in your storyboard with an `@IBOutlet`,

```
@IBOutlet weak var map : MKMapView!
```

or if you are manually creating your view hierarchy, instantiate a MKMapView with a default value.

```
var map : MKMapView! = MKMapView()
```

I recommend the former.

Comment: I dont get the error anymore but the map doesnt show up for some reason.There is just a black sceen.

Comment: This post recommends linking your project with the CoreGraphics.framework

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037700/mkmapview-showing-blank-screen-in-ios-8

Comment: Still getting a black screen and no map.